# 8ball embed command fails to launch

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to re-do my bot's 8ball command, I try to use the following code

```py
@client.command(aliases=['8ball'])
async def _8ball(ctx, *, question):
    responses = ['It is certain.',
                 'It is decidedly so.',
                 'Without a doubt.',
                 'Yes - definitely.',
                 'You may rely on it.',
                 'As I see it, yes.',
                 'Most likely.',
                 'Outlook good.',
                 'Yes.',
                 'Signs point to yes.',
                 'Reply hazy, try again.',
                 'Ask again later.',
                 'No.',
                 'Better not tell you now.',
                 'Cannot predict now.',
                 'Concentrate and ask again.',
                 "Don't count on it.",
                 'My reply is no.',
                 'My sources say no.',
                 'Outlook not so good.',
                 'Very doubtful.']
    responses = random.choice(responses)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="8ball", description="Ask the 8ball!", color=discord.Color.dark_purple())
    embed.add_field(name="Q: {question}", value="A: {responses}", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

But the python file refuses to launch, and returns

```
  File "C:\Users\r00t_technologies\Documents\bot\enigmatic-peak-21114\bot_development.py", line 135
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    ^
SyntaxError: 'await' outside function
```

Is anyone able to help me with this issue?

EDIT: Nevermind I'm just an idiot and was looking at the wrong line, sorry for the inconvienience (I am somewhat inexperienced at this)

Comment: Which `discord.py` version do you use? I see nothing wrong with the code in the first place and it works fine for me. Are you sure it comes from this command?

Answer (score -1):

You need to have more than one aliases in the aliases =. Try [‘8ball’, ‘8b’]